# use QuerySelectorAll to get element in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page where it is completely replaced by another html. Page source has my element, but DOM does not have it.

Following is my `jQuery` code, which works fine:

```
var account = parseInt($(".adajacent_links.pd0").find("li").first().text());
```

Whereas following code only works before replacing the content. It does not work after the DOM is replaced.

```
var account = parseInt(document.querySelectorAll(".adajacent_links.pd0 > li:first-child")[0].innerText);
```

even `document.querySelectorAll(".adajacent_links")` or `document.querySelector(".adajacent_links")` is not returning anything . `adajacent_links` class is present only in the page source, but not in the DOM. How does it works fine in `jQuery`?

Comment: Since you just want to return a single element, use `querySelector` and no `[0]`.

Comment: The two selectors are a bit different.  The first one will locate any `li` at any level within `.adajacent_links.pd0`.  The second one will only locate `li` that are direct children, because of `>`

Comment: It probably doesn't matter since it's identical in both, but maybe you spelt adjacent wrong?